# Substring Not Being Found Due to Blank Space and Special Characters

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I'm trying to find a substring from a dataframe based off a created list but it's not able to find substrings that have spaces in them. For example, the campaign_namecolumn has a string --AmazonPrime_)ofi9_aus and in the app_list it's Amazon Prime Video. The code isn't able to recognize the substring since it's AmazonPrime and not Amazon Prime. The same applies for Amazon Music and Google Photos. How would I adjust the code so it recognizes the substring regardless or not there is no space?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = ['-Net flix_ios_App-"',
        '--You_tube_',
        '..Tik_Tok_5dgj_USA',
        '-AmazonMusic: Songs& Podcast_95ikj_eu',
        'My FitnessPal_Fds34',
        'Tidalmusic_ios_and',
        '--AmazonPrime_)ofi9_aus',
        '--AS_Googlephotos_43ks_id3']

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["campaign_name"])

app_list = ['Netflix',
               'YouTube',
               'TikTok',
               'Amazon Music: Songs & Podcasts',
               'MyFitnessPal',
               'Tidal Music',
               'Amazon Prime Video'
               'Google Photos']

app_updated_names = [df["campaign_name"].str.lower()\
             .str.contains(app.lower())
             for app in app_list]

df["new_name"] = np.select(app_updated_names, app_list)
```

Additionally, would it be better if I just did `np.where` instead of referring to a list? For example,

```
df['new_name'] = np.where(df.campaign_name.str.contains('Netflix'), 'Netflix',
                       np.where(df.campaign_name.str.contains('Amazon Music'), 'Amazon Music','New app'))
```

This method is able to match string to the substring but I figured a list would be cleaner. Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend creating a function that can find a proper app name within a garbled bit of text, and using the pandas `apply()` function.

```py
import pandas as pd
import re

alpha_pattern = re.compile("[^a-zA-Z]")

# maps full app names to the minimum sequence of characters
# that a string must have in order for it to be labeled as that app.
# these identifiers are all in lowercase and don't have any
# non-alphabetic characters.
app_name_to_identifier = {
    "Netflix":"netflix",
    "YouTube":"youtube",
    "TikTok":"tiktok",
    "Amazon Music: Songs & Podcasts": "amazonmusic",
    "MyFitnessPal": "myfitnesspal",
    "Tidal Music": "tidalmusic",
    "Amazon Prime Video": "amazonprime",
    "Google Photos": "googlephoto"
}

data = ['-Net flix_ios_App-"',
        '--You_tube_',
        '..Tik_Tok_5dgj_USA',
        '-AmazonMusic: Songs& Podcast_95ikj_eu',
        'My FitnessPal_Fds34',
        'Tidalmusic_ios_and',
        '--AmazonPrime_)ofi9_aus',
        '--AS_Googlephotos_43ks_id3']

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["campaign_name"])




def find_proper_app_name(text:str):
    # reduce text to just lowercase alphabetic characters
    squished_text = alpha_pattern.sub("", text).lower()

    # search for app identifier within squished_text and return full name if found
    for proper_app_name, app_identifier in app_name_to_identifier.items():
        if app_identifier in squished_text:
            return proper_app_name
    return None


df['new_name'] = df['campaign_name'].apply(find_proper_app_name)
```

To make the problem easier, i'm using a regex pattern on the garbled text that will find all non A-Z characters and can be used with the `sub` method to remove them. And i'm also changing the text to lowercase to avoid case mismatches. This will turn "--AS_Googlephotos_43ks_id3" into "asgooglephotosksid".

I've also created a dictionary that maps proper app names, to the minimum sequence of characters that you'd need to see in the transformed text above in order to know it's from that app. In this case i think "googlephoto" without the "s" is enough to be confident.

Then I iterate through all the items in the dictionary and return the proper app name when i find and identifier that exists withing the squished garbled text. "googlephoto" is in "asgooglephotosksid" so "Google Photos" will be returned.

The pandas apply function will take the column it's called on (`campaign_name`) and pass those values to the function you've supplied it (`find_proper_app_name`). The result is the list of values you'd get if you applied the function to those column values individually.

There are a few caveats here.

1. This is meant for english text. It will throw away non-ASCII letters and you'd need to modify it to do the same thing in other languages.
2. This only works if you can be confident that those app identifier sequences will exist in the text, and will not exist in text that you don't want to match. For instance, i've used 'amazonprime' as an identifier for 'Amazon Prime Video', but that will obviously get anything that uses 'amazon prime' as part of its name. This particular case is more of a problem with the data, since the data really doesn't specify which amazon prime app it is. But there could be other problematic text.

If you find problems, you can always modify way the matching works to cover more cases.